# re:salad dressing shelf storage

Tags: food-safety, salad

can I process salad dressing for shelf life in a water bath or pressure canner and if I can how long is the process time, I can't find out anything about it please help.

Answer (score 2):

It REALLY depends on the recipe you are using.
Lots of salad dressings contain either dairy or oil and neither of these can be safely waterbathed OR pressure canned.

Something like a seasoned vinegar might be okay though however I am unable to give advice on how to process that safely.

check http://nchfp.uga.edu/ for guidelines and safe processes and recipes (their search feature on their website is pretty good)